# Problem with Static Friction. Two blocks on a platform

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction, free-body-diagram

everyone.

This problem is easy if you assume that the friction between the blocks and the platform is the maximum possible (i.e. when the friction force is $Fr_i=\mu_{est}m_ig$) . Then the normal force is 0. But how can you show that the normal is 0 even when the friction is less than maximum?

Thank you for your help.

[image]

---

Here are the equations I get for the normal forces
\begin{align*}
N_{21}&=-N_{12}\\
N_{21}&=\frac{m_2F_{r1}-m_1F_{r2}}{m_2+m_1}
\end{align*}
Clearly, when $F_{r1}=\mu_{est}m_1g$ and  $F_{r2}=\mu_{est}m_2g$ the interaction force between the blocks is 0.  This condition is fulfilled even when the blocks are sliding, because in this case $F_{r1}=\mu_{k}m_1g$ and  $F_{r2}=\mu_{k}m_2g$.

Comment: Which normal force is zero?

Comment: Hi Steeven, the normal force between the surfaces of block 1 and block 2. The contact force between the blocks.

Comment: Alright, by normal force you are referring to the interaction force between them which the question asks to. I'll provide and answer in a moment.

Comment: Yes, the interaction force between them when the friction is less than maximum.

Comment: @Steeven hi, looks like your answer is deleted (I was following the question so I received a notification about an answer, but I cannot see it now). I don't know why it is deleted, but I was interested in reading the answer so would it be possible for you to provide a screenshot? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @AshishAhuja, my apologies. I misunderstood the question gravely initially, so I deleted the question until I had time to revise it. I have now made a new and better answer below.

Answer (score 2):

*I misunderstood the question with my first answer. Here's a better one.*

The two blocks will, when the surface underneath them starts accelerating, stay stationary, influenced by static friction, until the surface accelerates so much that they individually break free from static friction and start sliding and lagging behind, influenced by kinetic friction instead. Let's consider the static and dynamic parts separately:

**Static part.** At small surface accelerations, both blocks remain stuck due to static friction, $f_s$. With the surface accelerating with $a$, in this situation Newton's 2st law gives us:
$$f_{s1}=m_1a\qquad\text{and}\qquad f_{s2}=m_2a.$$
At higher surface accelerations they will break out of static friction and start lagging behind when they individually reach their static-friction limit:
$$f_s\leq \mu_s n=\mu_s mg,$$
corresponding to:
$$\require{cancel}\mu_s\cancel{m_1}g=\cancel{m_1}a_\text{limit1}\qquad\text{and}\qquad \mu_s\cancel{m_2}g=\cancel{m_2}a_\text{limit2}\\
\Updownarrow \\
\mu_sg=a_\text{limit1}\qquad\text{and}\qquad \mu_sg=a_\text{limit2}.$$
It here turns out that $a_\text{limit1}=a_\text{limit2}$, meaning they will both break free from static friction at the same acceleration. So, for low surface accelerations up to this limit, the blocks don't move relatively to each other and thus the interaction force is zero.

**Dynamic part.** When the surface acceleration is above the static-friction limit, both block will simultaneously start to move relatively to the surface, meaning they will both start lagging behind, sliding backwards. Kinetic friction,
$$f_k=\mu_k n=\mu_kmg,$$
will appear on both, so Newton's 2nd law becomes:
$$f_{k1}=m_1a_1\qquad\text{and}\qquad f_{k2}=m_2a_2
\\ \Updownarrow \\
\mu_k\cancel{m_1}g=\cancel{m_1}a_1\qquad\text{and}\qquad \mu_k\cancel{m_2}g=\cancel{m_2}a_2
\\ \Updownarrow \\
\mu_kg=a_1\qquad\text{and}\qquad \mu_kg=a_2.$$
Again it turns out that, during sliding, $a_1=a_2$ is always true. So the blocks will still acquire the exact some motion and will thus not move relatively to each other. The interaction force between will continue to remain constant, meaning at zero.

**Conclusion.** Note that the above analysis did not take the arrangement of the blocks on the surface into account. Thus it holds true regardless of whether the heavier block is in front or behind. It also holds true for the limiting case of $m_1=m_2$. Conclusion is that the interaction force will always be zero for this idealised scenario.

Comment: "They both feel the exact same kinetic friction" 
this is not correct, the kinetic friction is proportional to the weight and those aren't the same.

Comment: @CDanielRojasR You are right, I was too quick and misunderstood the obvious in the question. I have now changed the answer. Please have a look and let me know if you find a mistake.